# Cannot update ClamAV via freshclam after installing apparmor

Tags: updates, apparmor

I searched but didn't find an exact answer ... here is my problem:
Until now updating freshclam virus definitions for clamav was fine, but after installing apparmor, freshclam does not update. I get this error message for freshclam:

```
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav     /freshclam.log).
```

So  I looked at apparmor status, and I got this message mentioning freshclam:

```
apparmor module is loaded.
50 profiles are loaded.
17 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
   /usr/bin/evince
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/freshclam
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//browser_java
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//browser_openjdk
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//sanitized_helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
   /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
33 profiles are in complain mode.
   /sbin/klogd
   /sbin/syslog-ng
   /sbin/syslogd
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//chromium_browser_sandbox
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//lsb_release
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//xdgsettings
   /usr/lib/dovecot/anvil
   /usr/lib/dovecot/auth
   /usr/lib/dovecot/config
   /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
   /usr/lib/dovecot/dict
   /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-auth
   /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda
   /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
   /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
   /usr/lib/dovecot/lmtp
   /usr/lib/dovecot/log
   /usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve
   /usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve-login
   /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
   /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
   /usr/lib/dovecot/ssl-params
   /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon
   /usr/sbin/dnsmasq
   /usr/sbin/dovecot
   /usr/sbin/identd
   /usr/sbin/mdnsd
   /usr/sbin/nmbd
   /usr/sbin/nscd
   /usr/sbin/smbd
   /usr/{sbin/traceroute,bin/traceroute.db}
   /{usr/,}bin/ping
10 processes have profiles defined.
1 processes are in enforce mode.
   /usr/sbin/cupsd (30306) 
0 processes are in complain mode.
9 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
   /sbin/dhclient (3729) 
   /usr/bin/freshclam (1639) 
   /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon (1507) 
   /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon (1508) 
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (1246) 
   /usr/sbin/dnsmasq (1754) 
   /usr/sbin/nmbd (1927) 
   /usr/sbin/smbd (1069) 
   /usr/sbin/smbd (1644)
```

So when I use sudo apt-get update, will that update my virus definitions next time or not?
Or do I need to "disable one profile" in apparmor for freshclam?

Any advice please, appreciate any feedback or guidance. I am a new user.